# How to unnest samples from a fable R forecast model

Tags: r, forecasting, tidy, fable, tidyverts

I am trying to get the samples from a forecast model generated with `fable`. This is what I tried

```
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Forecasting with an ETS(M,Ad,A) model to Australian beer production
beer_fc <- aus_production %>%
  model(ets = ETS(log(Beer) ~ error("M") + trend("Ad") + season("A"))) %>%
  forecast(h = "3 years", bootstrap=TRUE, times = 5)

beer_fc %>% unnest(c(Beer))
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Input must be list of vectors
```

Here is the structure of the data `str(beer_fc$Beer[1])`:

```
> str(beer_fc$Beer[1])
dist [1:1] 
$ :List of 3
 ..$ dist     :List of 1
 .. ..$ x: num [1:5] 6.09 6.02 6.06 6 5.95
 .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "dist_sample" "dist_default"
 ..$ transform:function (.x)  
 .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "transformation"
 .. ..- attr(*, "inverse")=function (.x)  
 ..$ inverse  :function (.x)  
 ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "dist_transformed" "dist_default"
@ vars: chr "Beer"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to extract the 'dist' values into 'long' format, loop over the `list` column 'Beer', extract the values, assign it back to the 'Beer' and then `unnest`

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
beer_fc$Beer <- map(beer_fc$Beer, ~ .x[[1]]$x)
beer_fc %>%
       unnest(c(Beer))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 60 x 4
#   .model Quarter  Beer .mean
#   <chr>    <qtr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 ets    2010 Q3  6.02  402.
# 2 ets    2010 Q3  5.99  402.
# 3 ets    2010 Q3  6.05  402.
# 4 ets    2010 Q3  5.92  402.
# 5 ets    2010 Q3  5.99  402.
# 6 ets    2010 Q4  6.15  470.
# 7 ets    2010 Q4  6.15  470.
# 8 ets    2010 Q4  6.17  470.
# 9 ets    2010 Q4  6.17  470.
#10 ets    2010 Q4  6.12  470.
# … with 50 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pluck` to get values that you want to extract from any level and then `unnest`.

```
library(tidyverse)

beer_fc %>%
  mutate(value = map(Beer, purrr::pluck, 'dist', 'x')) %>%
  unnest(value)

# A tibble: 60 x 5
#   .model Quarter         Beer .mean value
#   <chr>    <qtr>       <dist> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 ets    2010 Q3 t(sample[5])  402.  6.00
# 2 ets    2010 Q3 t(sample[5])  402.  6.02
# 3 ets    2010 Q3 t(sample[5])  402.  5.99
# 4 ets    2010 Q3 t(sample[5])  402.  6.05
# 5 ets    2010 Q3 t(sample[5])  402.  5.92
# 6 ets    2010 Q4 t(sample[5])  483.  6.21
# 7 ets    2010 Q4 t(sample[5])  483.  6.16
# 8 ets    2010 Q4 t(sample[5])  483.  6.14
# 9 ets    2010 Q4 t(sample[5])  483.  6.22
#10 ets    2010 Q4 t(sample[5])  483.  6.16
# … with 50 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{distributional}` package (used to provide these distribution objects) has since been updated with functions to obtain the shape and parameters of a distribution. These functions are recommended instead of unclassing the distributions, as the internal representation of these distributions may change in the future.

For example, take a Normal distribution:

```r
library(distributional)
fc <- dist_normal(10, 3)
```

Obtain the parameters from the distribution

```r
parameters(fc)
#>   mu sigma
#> 1 10     3
```

Obtain the shape of the distribution

```r
family(fc)
#> [1] "normal"
```

For your example…

```r
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
beer_fc <- tsibbledata::aus_production %>%
  model(ets = ETS(log(Beer) ~ error("M") + trend("Ad") + season("A"))) %>%
  forecast(h = "3 years", bootstrap=TRUE, times = 5)
```

You could extract the parameters and family

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
beer_fc %>% 
  mutate(parameters(Beer), family(Beer))
#> # A fable: 12 x 6 [1Q]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model Quarter      Beer .mean x         `family(Beer)`
#>    <chr>    <qtr>    <dist> <dbl> <list>    <chr>         
#>  1 ets    2010 Q3 sample[5]  411. <dbl [5]> sample        
#>  2 ets    2010 Q4 sample[5]  486. <dbl [5]> sample        
#>  3 ets    2011 Q1 sample[5]  426. <dbl [5]> sample        
#>  4 ets    2011 Q2 sample[5]  382. <dbl [5]> sample        
#>  5 ets    2011 Q3 sample[5]  409. <dbl [5]> sample        
#>  6 ets    2011 Q4 sample[5]  487. <dbl [5]> sample        
#>  7 ets    2012 Q1 sample[5]  424. <dbl [5]> sample        
#>  8 ets    2012 Q2 sample[5]  390. <dbl [5]> sample        
#>  9 ets    2012 Q3 sample[5]  407. <dbl [5]> sample        
#> 10 ets    2012 Q4 sample[5]  483. <dbl [5]> sample        
#> 11 ets    2013 Q1 sample[5]  425. <dbl [5]> sample        
#> 12 ets    2013 Q2 sample[5]  390. <dbl [5]> sample
```

Now the `x` variable contains a simple list of numbers that you can use `unnest()` or other functions to work with.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>