# Unnest <dist> column from `fabletools::forecast()` output

Tags: r, forecasting, fable-r, fabletools

I am asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960943/how-to-unnest-samples-from-a-fable-r-forecast-model) again because those answers don't work for my environment (see "Session Info" below), and thus I assume, don't work for the current versions of the relevant packages.

## Question

How can I take the elements of a `<dist>` column output by `fabletools::forecast()` and place each element in a new column of a `fable` (convertible to a `data.frame`)? E.g., all the `mu` elements in `mu`, `sigma` elements in `sigma`, etc.

## Old Answers Fail

```r
library(magrittr)
data(aus_production, package = "tsibbledata")
aus_production %>% 
    fabletools::model(ets_log = fable::ETS(log(Beer) ~ error("M") + trend("Ad") + season("A")),
                      ets = fable::ETS(Beer ~ error("M") + trend("Ad") + season("A"))) %>% 
    fabletools::forecast(h = "6 months")
#> # A fable: 4 x 4 [1Q]
#> # Key:     .model [2]
#>   .model  Quarter              Beer .mean
#>   <chr>     <qtr>            <dist> <dbl>
#> 1 ets_log 2010 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0013))  407.
#> 2 ets_log 2010 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0014))  483.
#> 3 ets     2010 Q3       N(408, 237)  408.
#> 4 ets     2010 Q4       N(483, 340)  483.

beer_fc <- aus_production %>% 
    fabletools::model(ets_log = fable::ETS(log(Beer) ~ error("M") + trend("Ad") + season("A")),
                      ets = fable::ETS(Beer ~ error("M") + trend("Ad") + season("A"))) %>% 
    fabletools::forecast(h = "6 months")

str(beer_fc$Beer[1])
#> dist [1:1] 
#> $ :List of 3
#>  ..$ dist     :List of 2
#>  .. ..$ mu   : num 6.01
#>  .. ..$ sigma: num 0.036
#>  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "dist_normal" "dist_default"
#>  ..$ transform:function (Beer)  
#>  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "transformation"
#>  .. ..- attr(*, "inverse")=function (Beer)  
#>  ..$ inverse  :function (Beer)  
#>  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "dist_transformed" "dist_default"
#> @ vars: chr "Beer"
class(beer_fc$Beer)
#> [1] "distribution" "vctrs_vctr"   "list"


##### Answer 1 fails (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960991/15723919)
beer_fc$Beer2 <- purrr::map(beer_fc$Beer, ~ .x[[1]]$x)
beer_fc %>% 
    tidyr::unnest(c(Beer2))
#> # A tibble: 0 × 5
#> # … with 5 variables: .model <chr>, Quarter <qtr>, Beer <dist>, .mean <dbl>,
#> #   Beer2 <???>


##### Answer 2 fails (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64963665/15723919)
beer_fc %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(value = purrr::map(Beer, purrr::pluck, 'dist', 'x')) %>% 
    tidyr::unnest(value)
#> # A tibble: 0 × 6
#> # … with 6 variables: .model <chr>, Quarter <qtr>, Beer <dist>, .mean <dbl>,
#> #   Beer2 <list>, value <???>


##### Change 'x' to something else for Answers 1 and 2
beer_fc$Beer2 <- purrr::map(beer_fc$Beer, ~ .x[[1]][["mu"]])
#> Error in `vec_slice()`:
#> ! Can't use character names to index an unnamed vector.

#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. ├─purrr::map(beer_fc$Beer, ~.x[[1]][["mu"]])
#>  2. │ └─global .f(.x[[i]], ...)
#>  3. │   └─.x[[1]][["mu"]]
#>  4. │     ├─base (local) `[[.distribution`(.x[[1]], "mu")
#>  5. │     └─vctrs:::`[.vctrs_vctr`(.x[[1]], "mu")
#>  6. │       └─vctrs:::vec_index(x, i, ...)
#>  7. │         └─vctrs::vec_slice(x, i)
#>  8. └─rlang::abort(message = message)
beer_fc %>% 
    tidyr::unnest(c(Beer2))
#> # A tibble: 0 × 5
#> # … with 5 variables: .model <chr>, Quarter <qtr>, Beer <dist>, .mean <dbl>,
#> #   Beer2 <???>


beer_fc %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(value = purrr::map(Beer, purrr::pluck, 'dist', 'mu')) %>% 
    tidyr::unnest(value)
#> # A tibble: 0 × 6
#> # … with 6 variables: .model <chr>, Quarter <qtr>, Beer <dist>, .mean <dbl>,
#> #   Beer2 <list>, value <???>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## Structure of Ideal Output

My ideal output looks like unnesting the elements of the `dist` column, however it's critical to extract the mu and sigma elements (or whatever the distribution parameters might be) in a rowwise fashion:

```
#> # A fable: 12 x 8 [1Q]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model   Quarter              Beer .mean    mu sigma transform inverse
#>    <chr>      <qtr>            <dist> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <chr>
#>  1 ets_log  2010 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0013))  407.  6.01 0.036 log       exp
#>  2 ets_log  2010 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0014))  483.   ...   ... ...       ...
#>  3 ets      2010 Q3       N(408, 237)  408.   408   237  NA        NA
#>  4 ets      2010 Q4       N(483, 340)  483.   ...   ... ...       ...
```

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       Etc/UTC
#>  date     2022-11-14
#>  pandoc   2.19.2 @ /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package        * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  anytime          0.3.9      2020-08-27 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  assertthat       0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  cli              3.4.0      2022-09-08 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  colorspace       2.0-3      2022-02-21 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  DBI              1.1.3      2022-06-18 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  digest           0.6.29     2021-12-01 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  distributional   0.3.1      2022-09-02 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  dplyr            1.0.10     2022-09-01 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  ellipsis         0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  evaluate         0.16       2022-08-09 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  fable            0.3.2      2022-09-01 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  fabletools       0.3.2      2021-11-29 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  fansi            1.0.3      2022-03-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  farver           2.1.1      2022-07-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  fastmap          1.1.0      2021-01-25 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  fs               1.5.2      2021-12-08 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  generics         0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  ggplot2          3.3.6      2022-05-03 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  glue             1.6.2      2022-02-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  gtable           0.3.1      2022-09-01 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  highr            0.9        2021-04-16 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  htmltools        0.5.3      2022-07-18 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  knitr            1.40       2022-08-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  lifecycle        1.0.2      2022-09-09 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  lubridate        1.8.0      2021-10-07 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  magrittr       * 2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  munsell          0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  numDeriv         2016.8-1.1 2019-06-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  pillar           1.8.1      2022-08-19 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  pkgconfig        2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  progressr        0.11.0     2022-09-02 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  purrr            0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  R6               2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  Rcpp             1.0.9      2022-07-08 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  reprex           2.0.2      2022-08-17 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  rlang            1.0.5      2022-08-31 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  rmarkdown        2.16       2022-08-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  rstudioapi       0.14       2022-08-22 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  scales           1.2.1      2022-08-20 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  sessioninfo      1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringi          1.7.8      2022-07-11 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringr          1.4.1      2022-08-20 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  tibble           3.1.8      2022-07-22 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyr            1.2.1      2022-09-08 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyselect       1.1.2      2022-02-21 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  tsibble          1.1.3      2022-10-09 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  utf8             1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  vctrs            0.4.1      2022-04-13 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  withr            2.5.0      2022-03-03 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  xfun             0.33       2022-09-12 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  yaml             2.3.5      2022-02-21 [1] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#>  [2] /usr/local/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Thanks for referencing the prior issue, I have posted an updated answer in there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the parameters from a distribution using the `parameters()` function. You can obtain the shape of the distribution using the `family()` function.

For example, you might have a Normally distributed forecast:

```r
library(distributional)
fc <- dist_normal(10, 3)
```

Obtain the parameters from the distribution

```r
parameters(fc)
#>   mu sigma
#> 1 10     3
```

Obtain the shape of the distribution

```r
family(fc)
#> [1] "normal"
```

For your example…

```r
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
fc <- tsibbledata::aus_production %>% 
  model(ets = ETS(log(Beer) ~ error("M") + trend("Ad") + season("A"))) %>% 
  forecast(h = "3 years")
```

You could extract the parameters and family

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
fc %>% 
  mutate(parameters(Beer), family(Beer))
#> # A fable: 12 x 8 [1Q]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model Quarter              Beer .mean           dist trans…¹ inverse famil…²
#>    <chr>    <qtr>            <dist> <dbl>         <dist> <list>  <list>  <chr>  
#>  1 ets    2010 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0013))  407.   N(6, 0.0013) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  2 ets    2010 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0014))  483. N(6.2, 0.0014) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  3 ets    2011 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0014))  419.   N(6, 0.0014) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  4 ets    2011 Q2   t(N(6, 0.0015))  384.   N(6, 0.0015) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  5 ets    2011 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0019))  405.   N(6, 0.0019) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  6 ets    2011 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0022))  481. N(6.2, 0.0022) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  7 ets    2012 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0023))  417.   N(6, 0.0023) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  8 ets    2012 Q2 t(N(5.9, 0.0025))  383. N(5.9, 0.0025) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  9 ets    2012 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0032))  403.   N(6, 0.0032) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#> 10 ets    2012 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0036))  479. N(6.2, 0.0036) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#> 11 ets    2013 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0039))  416.   N(6, 0.0039) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#> 12 ets    2013 Q2 t(N(5.9, 0.0043))  382. N(5.9, 0.0043) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​transform, ²​`family(Beer)`
```

Which produces the columns ‘dist’, ‘transform’ and ‘inverse’ - the parameters of the transformed distribution
However you’re probably more interested in the parameters of the Normal, which you can obtain from the `parameters()` of `dist`.

```r
fc %>% 
  mutate(parameters(Beer), family(Beer)) %>% 
  mutate(parameters(dist), family(dist))
#> # A fable: 12 x 11 [1Q]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model Quarter              Beer .mean           dist trans…¹ inverse famil…²
#>    <chr>    <qtr>            <dist> <dbl>         <dist> <list>  <list>  <chr>  
#>  1 ets    2010 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0013))  407.   N(6, 0.0013) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  2 ets    2010 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0014))  483. N(6.2, 0.0014) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  3 ets    2011 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0014))  419.   N(6, 0.0014) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  4 ets    2011 Q2   t(N(6, 0.0015))  384.   N(6, 0.0015) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  5 ets    2011 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0019))  405.   N(6, 0.0019) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  6 ets    2011 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0022))  481. N(6.2, 0.0022) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  7 ets    2012 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0023))  417.   N(6, 0.0023) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  8 ets    2012 Q2 t(N(5.9, 0.0025))  383. N(5.9, 0.0025) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#>  9 ets    2012 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0032))  403.   N(6, 0.0032) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#> 10 ets    2012 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0036))  479. N(6.2, 0.0036) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#> 11 ets    2013 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0039))  416.   N(6, 0.0039) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#> 12 ets    2013 Q2 t(N(5.9, 0.0043))  382. N(5.9, 0.0043) <fn>    <fn>    transf…
#> # … with 3 more variables: mu <dbl>, sigma <dbl>, `family(dist)` <chr>, and
#> #   abbreviated variable names ¹​transform, ²​`family(Beer)`
```

Or directly to the underlying (untransformed) distribution

```r
fc %>% 
  mutate(parameters(parameters(Beer)$dist))
#> # A fable: 12 x 6 [1Q]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model Quarter              Beer .mean    mu  sigma
#>    <chr>    <qtr>            <dist> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 ets    2010 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0013))  407.  6.01 0.0360
#>  2 ets    2010 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0014))  483.  6.18 0.0377
#>  3 ets    2011 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0014))  419.  6.04 0.0380
#>  4 ets    2011 Q2   t(N(6, 0.0015))  384.  5.95 0.0390
#>  5 ets    2011 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0019))  405.  6.00 0.0437
#>  6 ets    2011 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0022))  481.  6.17 0.0467
#>  7 ets    2012 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0023))  417.  6.03 0.0482
#>  8 ets    2012 Q2 t(N(5.9, 0.0025))  383.  5.95 0.0504
#>  9 ets    2012 Q3   t(N(6, 0.0032))  403.  6.00 0.0562
#> 10 ets    2012 Q4 t(N(6.2, 0.0036))  479.  6.17 0.0600
#> 11 ets    2013 Q1   t(N(6, 0.0039))  416.  6.03 0.0624
#> 12 ets    2013 Q2 t(N(5.9, 0.0043))  382.  5.94 0.0653
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was just digging into your code to see how you did it and found the reference to the `distributional` package. It looks like if I say `dplyr::mutate(mu = mean(Beer), var = distributional::variance(Beer))`, then a log-transform and original-units distribution both give me mean and variance in original units, which is useful for me. [Sorry I edited the question to highlight the multiple distribution angle before I saw your answer.] Amazing package! Thank you again!!

Comment: Yes, `mean()` and `variance()` will give you the means and variances of any distribution. If used on `Beer`, you would get the backtransformed means and variances of the forecasts.